# HTTP traffic with encrypted data

Tags: http, encryption, wireshark, payload

I've captured HTTP traffic with encrypted or encoded data. I've searched but I have no idea what kind of of a encryption this is. How can I decode this encryption?

```
GET  
/get/?data=/2XF6JRuMkt5KIcEG%2BYjfiDu9C0IiZqaNWW9rq0wxUvu8LH8vd4/V6fRsDQhfBI0Q4BCQR1zQcqeeaaRHR8Md/PWgnAObP5yDR3rJLTECYHHH0U5QhnEsaleqaexoCc9%2BC7z5UJnkzlDO4pIWjzw4TVwQ2F3W3EEjZh38DcfvKt2btc4PyjlCNmb9nJexw3ydMK%2B1DARk5QQ04MkInfqDmN3nhUOqZ1Uwjntxagrb85iE1rLzUjyu1ipw40wCmqtJgsmdHmMnGYAtljCfrGbr0EvcW/UFZKAsQUhfKMDDcffkFlcTzEQdYZOyigM11SWCypgeUGYTsM02o7p6sj6Cz2t/fqlc/Ro%2BytJ8ZO5a6H7mZvzQN0D3LMGnv1jpNRUyQVICHjumoYMpRN5soGXkWq5/xiRfBEzy9eX8wJNtfFC%2BhCqRTBaU1kuStZgxzNr2Uodo49lSCyZZiv0A10KLOvW3ZRlWLnkKK7VQlu2Xf8bcQ9PTJNTyEfU515ABtPdpgCew9Sx9bsl3dIY/MUSH/Plp9aNxqjYtkYq8/aWEU6ryhUENzSTJAeavefMO&version=4

HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know this for sure just by looking at it. [These](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used) answers explain it quite well. Basically, it's saying the "normal" way of going about doing this is reverse engineering from the application code. However, if that's not possible there are a few ways listed to help you make educated guesses.